# OpenGL glBufferSubData Offset issue

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a problem copying/upload all the data into the buffer using glBufferSubData(). I want to copy chunk by chunk to the buffer. So I have used this approach. I am seeing a blank screen when I try to render. Please find my code below. do you see any problem in calculating the buffer offset? Or is this not the way to copy data into the buffer?

Below is the data structure

```
struct DisplayIndexID {
        int idx;
        DrawStateT drawState;
        //Every display Index ID has its own draw models.
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<vertexModel>> readytoDrawModels;
    };


void initVboData(std::vector<DisplayIndexID> & v)

{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, geomVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(QVector3D) * 4096, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    std::vector<QVector3D> vecToDraw;
    GLintptr offset = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) 
        for (auto& vModel : v[i].readytoDrawModels)
        {
            if (vModel) {
                vecToDraw = vModel->getVertices();
                glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offset, sizeof(QVector3D) * vecToDraw.size(), &vecToDraw[0]);
                offset += sizeof(QVector3D) * vecToDraw.size(); // is this offset calculation fine?
            }
        }

 }

 //Below is my draw function

 void drawDisplayLists(std::vector<DisplayIndexID> & v) 
{
    initVboData(v);
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        //Make context current      
        makeCurrent();
        bool isTextureUsed = false;

        //Apply Projection Matrix.
        GLint mvp_mat = 0;
        GLint mvp_matText = 0;

        ///***********PRINT AREA***********************/
        for (auto& vModel : v[i].readytoDrawModels)
        {
         // Code related to Shaders
            ......


          glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
          glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(QVector3D), nullptr);  how to get the offset and add offset here. 

switch (vModel->getDrawMode())
    {
                case 0: //GL_POINTS
                    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, vModel->getVertices().size());
                    break;

                case 1: //GL_LINES
                    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, vModel->getVertices().size());
                    break;

                case 2: //GL_LINE_LOOP
                    glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, vModel->getVertices().size());
                    break;
              }  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `drawDisplayLists()` does not match `initVboData()` - you suddenly use `vModel` variable undefined in the method. If `drawDisplayLists()` iterates over `v` in the same way as initialization, then `glVertexAttribPointer()`  should be called with offsets in loop. Please add missing code in your quotation.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have updated my code in the edit section. Yes even drawDisplayLists() iterates over v in the same way as initialization. Please let me know how to add offset to glVertexAttribPointer() call. Thanks and very much appreciated.

Comment: @gkv311 *"then glVertexAttribPointer() should be called with offsets in loop"* - sorry but that is wrong. There are just vertex coordinates, so there is not any need for an offset. If you want to draw specific regions of the mesh, then you have to specify an offset and a different size at `glDrawArrays`

Comment: Thanks everyone. If I move the glBufferSubData() inside the drawDisplayList() under the for loop , it works. But I dont want to copy chunk every frame. This could be a performance hit.  So I thought of copying it before  and keep it ready before the frame starts. is there any way I can do this ?  because my vertices will not change. Everything is stored in Vectors. I have also tried copying the entire buffer using glBufferData(). This did not work. How to go about this? very much appreciated.

Comment: @Rabbid76 both `glVertexAttribPointer()` and `glDrawArrays()` can be used to specify an offset - where to do this depends on conditions. Passing offset to `glDrawArrays()`, when possible, will have probably a little bit less overhead.

Comment: @user284131 if entire model is persistent, then you may calculate offset in `drawDisplayLists()` in the same way as in `initVboData()`, otherwise (if, for instance, `readytoDrawModels` changes over time) you have to store offsets somewhere and implement some memory management to update VBO sub-regions.

Comment: @gkv311 Yes and No. The vertex specification is stored in the Vertex Array Object and should not be changed if it is not necessary.

Comment: @gkv311 thanks. I just want to pre upload the data into the buffer and render it. I don't have to calculate the offset if it is within the drawDispalyLists() . just calling std::vector<QVector3D> vecToDraw = vModel->getVertices(); glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(QVector3D) * vecToDraw.size(), &vecToDraw[0]); Will work. I dont want to upload within the DrawdisplayLists() beacuse of performance issue. There is no way we can preupload the chunks and just render in draw loop even though we have all the vertices ( i.e persistent) ?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have persistent VBO initialized like that:

```cpp
  GLintptr offset = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
    for (auto& vModel : v[i].readytoDrawModels) {
      if (vModel) {
        vecToDraw = vModel->getVertices();
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offset, sizeof(QVector3D) * vecToDraw.size(), &vecToDraw[0]);
        offset += sizeof(QVector3D) * vecToDraw.size();
      }
    }
  }
```

then you should replicate the same offsets within drawing loop.
This can be done either by passing offset in bytes to `glVertexAttribPointer()` computed exactly in the same way as during VBO initialization:

```cpp
  GLintptr offset = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
    for (auto& vModel : v[i].readytoDrawModels) {
      if (vModel) {
        vecToDraw = vModel->getVertices();
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(QVector3D), offset);
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, vecToDraw.size());
        offset += sizeof(QVector3D) * vecToDraw.size();
      }
    }
  }
```

or by passing offset in number of vertices to `glDrawArrays()`, in case if all models have the same vertex definition as in your code snippet (`in vec3 Position`):

```cpp
  GLintptr aFirstIndex = 0;
  glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(QVector3D), nullptr);
  for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
    for (auto& vModel : v[i].readytoDrawModels) {
      if (vModel) {
        vecToDraw = vModel->getVertices();
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, aFirstIndex, vecToDraw.size());
        aFirstIndex += vecToDraw.size();
      }
    }
  }
```

Make sure that allocated VBO has a proper size and 4096 is replaced by a real size:

```cpp
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(QVector3D) * 4096, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

By the way, grouping models by `GL_POINTS`/`GL_LINES` array type and same presentation attributes (color/material/etc.) would allow rendering each group with a single `glDrawArrays()` call, instead of numerous `glDrawArrays()` for every model, which would be more optimal from performance point of view.

Comment: Thanks a lot @gkv311. It worked. Awesome ! There is also some gain in performance.